# Control Back Location From Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have an app that has three activities.

- `Activity1` collects the data (numbers from the players of a sports game)
- `Activity2` displays `TextViews` that are clickable based on the data from `Activity1` (`Activity2` looks up the numbers entered from `Activity1` and shows links with the players' names).
- `Activity3` displays a `WebView` from the data in `Activity1` (it loads the player's web page from a sports web site) when the user clicks on one of the links.

I want to control the action of the "back" link in the label of the activity to go all the way back to `Activity1` from `Activity3` instead of going to `Activity2`. I'm assuming there is method for it, but I haven't been able to find it online or in the hints.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(DisplayNamesActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);

    WebView playerWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    playerWebView.loadUrl(message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you call Activity3 from Activity2? If so, you can use finish() method after calling Activity3 from Activity2.

Comment: That did not work.  It stopped erroring, but it does nothing now.  It does not go back.  Maybe we're not talking about the same thing.  There is a banner across the top with an arrow pointing to the left.  The text is set in the manifest as android:label.

Comment: I called finish() in the onOptionsItemSelected method of Activity 3.

Answer (score 2):

It actually has less to do with the behavior of the back button than it does with how `Activity2` is configured. In your `Android.Manifest`, put this flag in `Activity2`'s definition:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: That did not work.  It stopped erroring, but it does nothing now.  It does not go back.  Maybe we're not talking about the same thing.  There is a banner across the top with an arrow pointing to the left.  The text is set in the manifest as android:label.